# How to convert chunks of UTF-8 bytes to charcters?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a large UTF-8 input that is divided to 1-kB size chunks. I need to process it using a method that accepts String. Something like:

```
for (File file: inputs) {
     byte[] b = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
     String str = new String(b, "UTF-8");
     processor.process(str);
}
```

My problem is that I have no guarantee that any UTF-8 character is not split between two chunks. The result of running my code is that some lines end with '?', which corrupts my input.

What would be a good approach to solve this?

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Are you sure that inputs are not corrupt?  I.e. do these files contain valid 'UTF-8'?  One other thing, if you are running on Windows, sometimes UTF-8 encoded files have a magic bytes sequence at the start of the file, that is just binary data and must be skipped over, when passing to `String` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you had a large text, which was encoded with UTF-8, then split into 1-kilobyte files. Now you want to read the text back, but you are concerned that an encoded character might be split across file boundaries, and cause a UTF-8 decoding error.

The API is a bit dusty, but there is a [`SequenceInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#SequenceInputStream-java.util.Enumeration-) that will create what appears to be a single `InputStream` from a series of sub-streams. Create one of these with a collection of `FileInputStream` instances, then create an `InputStreamReader` that decodes the stream of UTF-8 bytes to text for your application.

Comment: SequenceInputStream wasn't good for me (since I didn't want to open all the files before I start) so I implemented my own InputStream. Thanks.

Comment: Good approach. Hopefully the example got you headed in the right direction.